# Progressbar not update in time

Tags: java, swt, progress-bar, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a problem. On my (eclipse 4 based) GUI I have two objects:

```
Button button = new Button(groupInitialize, SWT.NONE);
ProgressBar bar= new ProgressBar(group, SWT.SMOOTH);
```

I set a listner for the button so that any time that the button is pressed an elaboration begin. During this elaboration the status bar has to be updated.

```
// Button listener definition!
button .addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        myLongLastingMethod();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        new Thread(run).start();
    }
});
```

and this is what I do in the myLongLastingMethod():

```
private void myLongLastingMethod() {
    action1();
    update();

    action2();
    update();

    action3();
    update();
}
```

And finally the update method (which -should- update the progress bar):

**UPDATED**

```
private void update() {
    if (progressBar.isDisposed()) {
        return;
    }
    int selection = progressBar.getSelection();
    progressBar.setSelection(++selection);
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong ... Any idea/help why it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Your background thread `Runnable` is using `display.asyncExec` to call your long running method. `display.asyncExec` runs the code in the User Interface thread, so nothing else will happen in the UI while that code is running. You should only use `asyncExec` to run short code which updates the UI.

Just call `myLongLastingMethod` directly in the background thread without the `asyncExec` call.

So:

```
public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           myLongLastingMethod();
        }
    };
    new Thread(run).start();
}
```

Comment: like this: public void handleEvent(final Event event) {myLongLastingMethod();}

?

Comment: No you still need to run a background thread, added code to answer.

Comment: ok I got it but still doesn't work as into the run method we're not in the UI thread (indeed I got an exception).

Comment: Forgot to say that into the myLongLastingMethod  I have to update some guy element + the progressbar.

Comment: Well what are you doing that needs to be in the UI thread other than the `update` call?  You need to split out things that can run in the background and don't touch the UI and things that need to update the UI. Anything that needs to update the UI from the background has to use `asyncExec`.

Comment: That's what I did in the code I've posted. I do use the async as I need to update the UI (progressBar) but it's not updated.

Comment: No, you called `asyncExec` to run the **entire** code, so everything ran in the UI thread and blocked everything else. Calling `asyncExec` from code which is already running in the UI thread just delays that code until after the current code has finished.

Comment: I see what you says! I had "nested" asyncExec elaboration. I've fixed now but the update of the progressBar happens once the myLongLastingMethod has finished. It is like the events of updating the progressBar are sent but are effectively updated after the (myLongLastingMethod) method complete its elaboration.

Comment: Well are you running `myLongLastingMethod` in the background thread like I said. If you run it in the UI thread that is exactly what will happen.

Comment: I got it but if I do like you proposed I get invalid thread access.

Comment: I have already told you that you must run the long running non-UI code in the background thread and everything in that code which touches anything to do with the UI must use a separate, small, `asyncExec` call to change the UI.